# Do open propellers experience pre-entry drag (additive drag) like an engine in nacelle?

Tags: aerodynamics, propeller, drag, nacelle

Engines in a nacelle experience [pre-entry](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930088243.pdf) (also called [additive](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/b023874.pdf)) drag.

Do unducted propellers experience it too?